# Implemented interface with co/contravariance generates compile time error

Tags: c#

I have implemented an interface with co/contravariant type constraints and the compiler is telling me that `'Student' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.IMail<T,U>'`

From what I can see, I'm satisfying those requirements. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Person { public Person(){} }
class Student : Person { public Student(){} }
class MatureStudent : Student {public MatureStudent(){}}

interface IMail<in T, out U> where T : new() where U : new() {
    void Receive(T t);
    U Return();
}

class Mail<Student,MatureStudent> : IMail<Student,MatureStudent> {
    public void Receive(Student s) {}
    public MatureStudent Return() { return new MatureStudent(); }
}
```

Comment: When you declare the class `Mail<,>`, you introduce two _new_ type parameters with the names `Student` and `MatureStudent`. So now `Student` can refer to two things: (1) the class with that name, and (2) the new type parameter of the `Mail<,>` class with that name. Some rule of C# dictates that (2) has higher "priority" than (1). But you should avoid using the same names for distinct things. See answer by Skeet.

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio (with usual settings) displays (1) with colored text, and (2) with black text. If you really wanted to keep the type parameters with the same names as the classes, you could still use the classes (1) if you specified namespace, so `YourNamespace.Student` instead of just `Student`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring `Mail` to be generic too - you've made `Student` and `MatureStudent` type parameters. You just want:

```
class Mail : IMail<Student,MatureStudent> {
```

Comment: I see. I wish the compiler had told me that.

Comment: @VincePanuccio: Well if you'd given `MatureStudent` a `new()` constraint, it would have been perfectly valid...